# ng-bootstrap : ReferenceError: Document is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, ng-bootstrap, angular-universal

I have an Angular 6 SSR app and i have added ng-bootstrap to it, but on SSR build and run, i get error bellow:

```
ReferenceError: Document is not defined
    at NgbFocusTrapFactory.ctorParameters (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2221:48333)
    at ReflectionCapabilities._ownParameters (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:76:1668)
    at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:76:2482)
    at JitReflector.parameters (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:3226:919)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2665:25829)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2665:23935)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableTypeMetadata (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2665:31300)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2665:31593)
    at J:\Java\workstation\front\.server\server.js:2665:29171
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Why i get `Document is not defined`? 
should i do something with **Webpack** or any thing else?

```
webpack : ^4.0.0
angular": 6.0.0-rc.6, 
ng-bootstrap: ^2.0.0,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **solved** this problem with [jsdom-global](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom-global).

> jsdom-global will inject document, window and other DOM API into your
>   Node.js environment. Useful for running, in Node.js, tests that are
>   made for browsers.

1) Run: `npm install --save-dev --save-exact jsdom jsdom-global`

2) Add: `require('jsdom-global')()` in vendor.ts